# Velocity solution like Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf, velocity

I would like to know if I can use Velocity Template like Thymeleaf when I have an object in Spring with attributes, let say, (product.courseName) and I want to send it to an HTML page this way

> h1 th:text="${product.courseName}" HTML Example Course Name /h1

so i can show it directly...

**Thymeleaf let me isolate the HTML development from the Spring Coding**, but I cannot find such a simple approach in Velocity. Can I show the HTML with "HTML Example Course Name" in a browser and the real Course Name from each object when Velocity executes (just like in Thymeleaf)?

PD: I would appreciate any documentation reference.

SPRING CONTROLLER

```
@RequestMapping("/product/{id}")
    public String getProductById(@PathVariable Integer id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("product", productService.getProduct(id));
        return "product";
    }
```

PRODUCT.HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 th:text="${product.courseName}">Course Name</h1>                    
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes but not exactly you are doing it. If you take a look the section [properties](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#properties) of the reference documentation it's explained how to do it:

> Properties
>
> The second flavor of VTL references are properties, and properties
>   have a distinctive format. The shorthand notation consists of a
>   leading $ character followed a VTL Identifier, followed by a dot
>   character (".") and another VTL Identifier. These are examples of
>   valid property references in the VTL:
>
> ```
> $customer.Address
> $purchase.Total
> ```

And aswell is explained, if you use it, it calls the getter of the property like `thymeleaf` surely does.

> `$customer.Address`. It can have two meanings. It can mean, Look in the
>   hashtable identified as customer and return the value associated with
>   the key Address. But $customer.Address can also be referring to a
>   method (references that refer to methods will be discussed in the next
>   section);
>
> `$customer.Address` could be an abbreviated way of writing
>   $customer.getAddress()
>
> ........

#### edited

So in resume, don't use thymeleaf tags like `th:text`.

```
<h1>$product.courseName</h1>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain clearly the problem (so I wrote it again). Thanks for help Pau!!! :-D

Comment: Using `<h1>` and `</h1>` is correct, but removing `{` and `}` is not necessary, since it corresponds to the Velocity's [formal reference notation](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#formal-reference-notation).